# How to create a new column containing part of the day (night, morning, afternoon,evening)

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I wish to create a new column that contains the part of the day .I would consider {night(00:01 to 6:00),morning(6:01 to 12:00), afternoon(12:01 to 18:00), evening(18:011 to 00:00)}
here is the dataframe :

```
   package_name       name                starttime  duration  UserId              
com.facebook.katana Facebook  2020-09-19 6:02:06.019     28.077        4                              
com.android.systemui  System UI  2020-09-19 16:42:34.096    28.077     4          
com.android.systemui  System UI  2020-09-19 19:51:35.778     0.329      4                                                com.facebook.katana   Facebook  2020-09-19 10:56:39.129     0.329            4            
com.android.systemui  System UI  2020-09-19 01:48:32.067     3.022       4
```

I found similar problems on the forum but I couldn't modify the code to work with my data.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
In [4249]: df.starttime = pd.to_datetime(df.starttime)
In [4253]: conditions = [df.starttime.dt.hour.between(0, 6), df.starttime.dt.hour.between(6, 12), df.starttime.dt.hour.between(12, 18), df.starttime.dt.hour.between(18,24)]

In [4254]: choices = ['night', 'morning', 'afternoon', 'evening']

In [4257]: df['part_of_day'] = np.select(conditions, choices)

In [4258]: df
Out[4258]: 
           package_name       name               starttime  duration  UserId part_of_day
0   com.facebook.katana   Facebook 2020-09-19 06:02:06.019    28.077       4       night
1  com.android.systemui  System UI 2020-09-19 16:42:34.096    28.077       4   afternoon
2  com.android.systemui  System UI 2020-09-19 19:51:35.778     0.329       4     evening
3  com.android.systemui  System UI 2020-09-19 01:48:32.067     0.329       4       night
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) here with convert datetimes to hours if performance is important:

```
df['starttime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['starttime'])

df['new'] = pd.cut(df['starttime'].dt.hour,
                   bins=[0,6,12,18,23],
                   labels=['night','morning','afternoon','evening'],
                   include_lowest=True)

print (df)
           package_name       name               starttime  duration  UserId  \
0   com.facebook.katana   Facebook 2020-09-19 06:02:06.019    28.077       4   
1  com.android.systemui  System UI 2020-09-19 16:42:34.096    28.077       4   
2  com.android.systemui  System UI 2020-09-19 19:51:35.778     0.329       4   
3   com.facebook.katana   Facebook 2020-09-19 10:56:39.129     0.329       4   
4  com.android.systemui  System UI 2020-09-19 01:48:32.067     3.022       4   

         new  
0      night  
1  afternoon  
2    evening  
3    morning  
4      night
```

Performance test for 5k rows:

```
df['starttime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['starttime'])

df = pd.concat([df] * 1000, ignore_index=True)


In [79]: %%timeit
    ...: conditions = [df.starttime.dt.hour.between(0, 6), df.starttime.dt.hour.between(6, 12), df.starttime.dt.hour.between(12, 18), df.starttime.dt.hour.between(18,24)]
    ...: 
    ...: choices = ['night', 'morning', 'afternoon', 'evening']
    ...: 
    ...: df['part_of_day'] = np.select(conditions, choices)
    ...: 
5.28 ms ± 451 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [80]: %%timeit
    ...: df['new'] = pd.cut(df['starttime'].dt.hour,
    ...:                    bins=[0,6,12,18,23],
    ...:                    labels=['night','morning','afternoon','evening'],
    ...:                    include_lowest=True)
    ...:                    
2.1 ms ± 13.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

And for 50k rows:

```
df['starttime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['starttime'])

df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)


In [82]: %%timeit
    ...: conditions = [df.starttime.dt.hour.between(0, 6), df.starttime.dt.hour.between(6, 12), df.starttime.dt.hour.between(12, 18), df.starttime.dt.hour.between(18,24)]
    ...: 
    ...: choices = ['night', 'morning', 'afternoon', 'evening']
    ...: 
    ...: df['part_of_day'] = np.select(conditions, choices)
    ...: 
    ...: 
26.9 ms ± 221 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [83]: %%timeit
    ...: df['new'] = pd.cut(df['starttime'].dt.hour,
    ...:                    bins=[0,6,12,18,23],
    ...:                    labels=['night','morning','afternoon','evening'],
    ...:                    include_lowest=True)
    ...:                    
7.46 ms ± 68.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```